# SO general opnet/riverbed questions ok?

Tags: discussion

Is SO the right stack exchange community to ask opnet/riverbed AppResponseXpert questions. I've tried riverbed forums, but haven't gotten any feedback. Not really sure I will here either, but I wanted to give it a shot.

Comment: That depends. What _sort_ of question would you ask? Can you add a sample question to your question here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Overflow is for **programming** questions. From what I can see those are **not** programming languages or have anything to do with programming.

So the answer is no. It is not a suitable site for such questions.

---

We do have Server Fault, which is a site for system administrators, which may be suitable for this topic, but you should read their help center documentation, in particular what's on-topic and what is not.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is a site for answering questions related to programming. Given that riverbed is a networking appliance those questions would not be on topic here.

However, Stack Exchange does have two sites that might be able to help you out in the form of [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) which is for "Network routing, switches, and firewalls" and also the new beta site [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) which is even more specialized. With any luck one of those sites will have some users who have experience with riverbed and be able to help you out.